# Regex to match continuous pattern of integer then space

Tags: java, regex

I'm asking the user for input through the `Scanner` in Java, and now I want to parse out their selections using a regular expression.  In essence, I show them an enumerated list of items, and they type in the numbers for the items they want to select, separated by a space.  Here is an example:

```
1   yorkshire terrier
2   staffordshire terrier
3   goldfish
4   basset hound
5   hippopotamus 

Type the numbers that correspond to the words you wish to exclude: 3 5
```

The enumerated list of items can be a just a few elements or several hundred.  The current regex I'm using looks like this `^|\\.\\s+)\\d+\\s+`, but I know it's wrong.  I don't fully understand regular expressions yet, so if you can explain what it is doing that would be helpful too!

Comment: You should use the split method.

Comment: To verify the input was given properly, I want to first check to be sure it fits the proper format using regular expressions.

Comment: Ok, I will give you a different method.

Comment: Don't use `\s` when you only want to match spaces.  Just use a literal space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Pattern pattern = new Pattern(^([0-9]*\s+)*[0-9]*$)
```

Explanation of the RegEx:

- ^ : beginning of input
- [0-9] : only digits
- '*' : any number of digits
- \s : a space
- '+' : at least one space
- '()*' : any number of this digit space combination
- $: end of input

This treats all of the following inputs as valid:

- "1"
- "123 22"
- "123             23"
- "123456 33 333 3333 "
- "12321      44    452      23 "

etc.

Comment: This works better since it allows for trailing spaces. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You want integers:

```
\d+
```

followed by any number of space, then another integer:

```
\d+( \d+)*
```

Note that if you want to use a regex in a Java string you need to escape every `\` as `\\`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  Will it work on an unspecified quantity of digits+spaces?  I want an integer followed by a an optional space and another (also optional) integer repeating.

Comment: any number of space would be <space>+, final expression is `\d+( +\d+)*`

Answer (score 0):

To "parse out" the integers, you don't necessarily want to *match* the input, but rather you want to split it on spaces (which uses regex):

```
String[] nums = input.trim().split("\\s+");
```

If you actually want `int` values:

```
List<Integer> selections = new ArrayList<>();
for (String num : input.trim().split("\\s+"))
    selections.add(Integer.parseInt(num));
```

Comment: I want to verify the user entered in proper input before trying to parse anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that your string contains only numbers and spaces (with a variable number of spaces and trailing/leading spaces allowed) and extract number at the same time, you can use the `\G` anchor to find consecutive matches.

```
String source = "1 3 5 8";

List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\G *(\\d++) *(?=[\\d ]*$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(source);

while (m.find()) {
    result.add(m.group(1));
}
for (int i=0;i<result.size();i++) {
    System.out.println(result.get(i));
}
```

Note: at the begining of a global search, `\G` matches the start of the string.